# Working on nintex flexi task through infopath form

Tags: infopath, tasks, 2016, nintex

In our SP 2016 environment, we have used infopath form to work on flexi tasks in nintex workflow. We have a strange case where if the task approver is having read access to site but contribute permission to the main list & task list and he tries to work on the task it doesn't go through. On subsequent re tries it throws "State Error".